# Is $AB = \emptyset$ if $A = \emptyset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of the of real numbers and let $AB = \{xy : x \in A, y \in B\}$.  My question is if $A$ is empty, will $AB$ be empty as well?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: yes. write out the definition

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Vacuously.

If $z\in AB$ then there is some $x\in A, y\in B$ such that $xy=z$. But $A=\varnothing$, so there is no such $x$ and no such $z$.

Answer (score 4):

Sure: if $A=\varnothing$, there are no pairs of the form $ab$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, so by definition $AB=\varnothing$.